# Solving this system of non-linear equations algorithmically with the Newton-Raphson method

Tags: optimization, roots, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

I'm looking [at this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3897396/822508) answer to a question about a localization problem in 3 dimensions. I believe the details of that problem are more or less irrelevant to this question, however OP concludes by determining the problem is reduces to the solution of the following non-linear system:

> Now, we need to minimize $\Phi(X,Y,Z,T)$. Writing the partial derivatives, we have to solve the four equations
> $$\frac{\partial \Phi(X,Y,Z,T)} {\partial X}= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \,\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial X}=0$$
> $$\frac{\partial \Phi(X,Y,Z,T)} {\partial Y}= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \,\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial Y}=0$$
> $$\frac{\partial \Phi(X,Y,Z,T)} {\partial Z}= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \,\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial Z}=0$$
> $$\frac{\partial \Phi(X,Y,Z,T)} {\partial T}= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \,\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial T}=0$$
> with
> $$\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial X}=\frac{X-x_i}{\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2}}$$
> $$\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial Y}=\frac{Y-y_i}{\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2}}$$
> $$\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial Z}=\frac{Z-z_i}{\sqrt{(X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2+(Z-z_i)^2}}$$
> $$\frac{\partial f_i} {\partial T}=v$$ This system of equations is quite easy to solve with Newton-Raphson method.

How, precisely, would such a system be solved by Newton-Raphson in practice? I've previously written an algorithm using Newton-Raphson to find the root of a *singular* non-linear equation, and it isn't obvious to me how this could be applied to a system such as this.

The end goal being to write an algorithmic solution (where simplicity is the utmost priority).

*Note that I'm aware other avenues exist. I'm simply interested in NR*

Comment: Search for "Multidimensional Newton-Raphson" or "Multivariate Newton-Raphson". You will find a lot of material like this one: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs471/multinewton.pdf